# Query half of value

Tags: mysql, sql

how can i query in PhpMyAdmin a mySQL DB tabel column for all values were the first half of the string (the values are strings) contains a given string? like:

```
SELECT * FROM `tabel` WHERE first_half_of_string(`column`) = %'search_for_string'%;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `substring` to do this.

```
SELECT * FROM `tabel` 
WHERE substring(`column`, 1, length(`column`)/2) like %'search_for_string'%;
```

To handle even and odd lengths of the column, use

```
SELECT * FROM `tabel` 
WHERE substring(`column`, 1, if(mod(length(`column`),2)=0, length(`column`)/2, 1+length(`column`)/2) like %'search_for_string'%;
```

Comment: extract from half to the end..`substring(`column`,  length(`column`)/2)

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 
WHERE SUBSTRING(colum1,1,LENGTH(colum1)/2) LIKE '%search_for_string%';
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation of your answer to help other users of the site. Code-only answers are not very useful and tend to be marked as low quality and potentially deleted.